# Cloud Firestore - does a realtime listener update count as a read operation?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Say I am listening on a document:

```
db.collection("cities").document("SF")
    .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
      guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
        print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
        return
      }
      print("Current data: \(document.data())")
    }
```

Would each time the data is updated count as a read operation, or does the act of listening count itself, according the [Firestore billing policy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing)?

Also, say I am listening on a number of documents:

```
db.collection("cities").whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA")
    .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        let cities = documents.map { $0["name"]! }
        print("Current cities in CA: \(cities)")
    }
```

Will I be charged for a read operation immediately on all documents that match the query or on each update to each document - or both?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The act of listening does not itself count as a read, however there is a minimum of one document charged per query. From the pricing page, under "Minimum charge for queries":

> There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.

The initial read and the updates both count. However if you re-listen a short while after you've already done so, you won't get charged for documents that haven't changed since you listened last. Currently that short while threshold is 30 minutes. That's also on there, under "Listening to query results":

> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read each time a document in the result set is added or updated
>
> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query.

Comment: I have a small doubt between listen and read. I understant the cost for "Listening to query results". But let say I am reading a document data with `get()` method. So the cost is 1 read. Now if I go the same read within 30 minuts will I be charged or it will also fall under the free listeneing for 30 minuts concept. Could you please help me to understand this?

Comment: Listening to query results and getting them once have the same billing behavior. If you call `get()` once, then again in less than 30 minutes, and the value has not changed you won't be charged for the second get.

Comment: If am getting the total number of count from a collection, will that be considered as read operation?

Comment: @Mac_Play, Firestore doesn't have a count operation, so I don't really know what you're doing. You should open a new question with the details of which SDK you're doing and how you're counting. Absent that, from what I know, every document that's in a query result, regardless of whether or not you look at its contents, counts as a read.

Comment: How do I re-list to the SnapshotListener? Just by adding and removing it?

Comment: What I meant by re-listen was if you stopped listening and then listened to the same query again. Usually you stop listening because your user moves away from the view that needed the data or they close your app. When they reopen the app (or the view) you start listening again.

Comment: @GilGilbert Has this billing policy changed? I just checked my app, and it seems like each re-listening is counted even though they occurred within 30 minutes.

Comment: I checked the reference where it says if offline persistence is disabled, each listen will be counted, but I didn't turn the setting off. I'm going to try updating the library to the latest version and see if the problem goes away.